# How do I write multiple commands under CMD tag in Dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have the following command in my start.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash    
cd /opt/app
    ../node_modules/.bin/nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 & swagger project edit -s -p 81 --host 0.0.0.0
```

which I wish to execute when the container is brought up. What should be the corresponding `CMD` syntax in Dockerfile?

Comment: You _don't_ want to use this `start.sh` file then, you want all of this in a `CMD`?

Answer (score 1):

You could call start.sh with CMD. e.g.:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN mkdir -p /src/app
WORKDIR /src/app
COPY . .

CMD ["/bin/bash", "/src/app/start.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Often if you're running two totally separate servers, it's just as easy to run them in two separate containers.

```sh
docker run ... -p 9229:9229 -d imagename \
  npm run nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229
docker run ... -p 9281:81 -d imagename \
  swagger project edit -s -p 81 --host 0.0.0.0
```

If for whatever reason `nodemon` dies, in your shell script example, Docker simply won't notice.  On the flip side, if `swagger` dies, it will take `nodemon` with it.  If you run two separate containers, you can see the `docker logs` of the two things separately, and you can specify a `--restart` policy if that helps you.